# Uncountable connected graph such that complement is also connected

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

Is there a connected simple undirected graph $G=(V, E)$ such that $|V| > \aleph_0$ and the complement of $G$ is also connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Let $V$ be a large enough ordinal. For $x\in V$ add an edge to $x+1$ and also add edges between any two non-successor ordinals in $V$.

Answer (score 6):

Sure.  Here's a construction that works for any vertex set $V$ with at least $4$ points.  Split $V$ into two sets $A$ and $B$ which both have at least two elements, and let $G$ be the complete bipartite graph with respect to the partition $V=A\cup B$ with one edge removed.  Since one edge was removed, the complement of $G$ is connected; since both $A$ and $B$ have at least two points, it is easy to show that $G$ is connected.