# Infinite graph with finite diameter such that complement has also finite diameter

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a connected simple undirected graph $G=(V, E)$ with finite diameter such that $|V| \geq \aleph_0$ and the complement of $G$ is also connected and has finite diameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[My answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1447667/86856) to your previous question works just as well for this one ($G$ has diameter $2$ and its complement has diameter $3$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal number, and let $G=L(K_\kappa)$ be the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of a complete graph of order $\kappa.$ If $\kappa\gt4$ then both $G$ and its complement $\bar G$ have diameter $2.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The [Rado graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph) $R$ is a countably infinite graph with diameter $2$ whose complement also has diameter $2$.

The Rado graph is characterized by extension properties: Given any two finite disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $R$, there is a vertex $v$ in $R$ such that $v$ is adjacent to every vertex in $A$ and $v$ is not adjacent to every vertex in $B$.

Given any two vertices $x$ and $y$, there is some $v$ which is a adjacent to both of them ($A = \{x,y\}$) and some $w$ which is not adjacent to either of them ($B = \{x,y\}$).